# Chrome extension PNaCl access background.js file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

Is it possible to open an extensions *background.js* file in read mode directly from the [PNaCl](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/nacl-and-pnacl) module ([Chromium Projects Docs](https://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl))? I wanted to be able to read the contents of that file, but I couldn't find any information on that topic.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: @noogui I read the doc - https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/file-io and i ran that sample code. I was unable to browse extension directory.